# Indicator Array of ROI in PyQtgraph

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5, numpy-ndarray, pyqtgraph

Here is a snippet of code slightly modified from one of pyqtgraph examples:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pyqtgraph as pg

pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')

## Create image to display
image = cv2.imread('panda.jpg')

#Transpose the image
def picturetranspose(picture):
    shape = picture.shape
    result = np.empty((shape[1],shape[0],shape[2]),dtype= np.uint8)
    for i in range(0,3):
        result[:,:,i] = np.transpose(picture[:,:,i])
    return result
    
arr = np.rot90(picturetranspose(image))
app = pg.mkQApp("ROI Examples")
w = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, size=(1000,800), border=True)
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ROI Examples')

w1 = w.addLayout(row=0, col=0)
v1a = w1.addViewBox(row=1, col=0, lockAspect=True)
img1a = pg.ImageItem(arr)
v1a.addItem(img1a)


rois = []
rois.append(pg.PolyLineROI([[80, 60], [90, 30], [60, 40]], pen=(6,9), closed=True))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

Here the image "panda.jpg" is given by:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ejY0CjfEwS6SGS2qe_uRX2JvlruMKvPX?usp=sharing.

By an `indicator array` of an ROI subject to an image, we mean the array that has the same size as image, takes value 1 in the region enclosed by ROI, and takes value 0 in the region outside of ROI . How do I code out a method for the above situation to return me the indicator array of the polylineRoi subject to the image `arr` ?

I personally find this a hard task as I cannot find a direct link in the documentation between the ROI and the size of image item .

Comment: By `indicator array` are you referring to a mask?

Comment: Yes. You can also call it a mask.

Comment: Does this [link]https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/roi.html help? And this too [link[https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/113018/pyqtgraph.ROI

Comment: I have consulted these links already but still cannot figure out a solution.