# Relation between `pos` and `ROI`

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, roi

In the documentation https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/roi.html, it is mentioned that the `pos` argument "(length-2 sequence) Indicates the position of the ROI’s origin. For most ROIs, this is the lower-left corner of its bounding rectangle . "

In practice (for example [Indicator Array of ROI in PyQtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396576/indicator-array-of-roi-in-pyqtgraph)), it turns out often that when I move my ROI or change the location of the points involved in ROI, the `pos` argument also changes despite that I never use a command to change the origin of the ROI (I wish it to stay at `(0,0)`). Is there any intuitive explanation about why such change happens and how does it happen ?

Comment: I don't understand your problem - if you move ROI then it moves position of `"its bounding rectangle"` and it moves its `"lower-left corner"` and this is `pos` - so `pos` is changing. If you  would keep `pos` then you would have to keep `"lower-left corner"` of `ROI` in position `(0,0)`